# retain element values selenium chrome python

Tags: selenium, element, retain

I am using selenium-chrome webdriver for logging into a website.
In Page -1 , I am selecting values for multiple fields (includes text fields/drop down etc) and click submit on page 1. This opens page2 and by clicking on 'Generate button' - it downloads an excel file.
Now i need to go back to Page1 and change JUST one value of a drop down field in page 1 and generate another file (same process).
But problem I am facing is, after coming back from Page2, values which were already set in Page1 is refreshed /lost. 
How can i make sure, earlier values are not lost, during this process.

Thanks in advance.
Regards,

Comment: Why do you want to keep those values? Any specific reason? Why don't you fill those values again?

Comment: there are 10-15 values in that page which I have set initially. For the second file, I just need to update only one field. So i thought why should I do the same value setting process again.

Answer (score 0):

As you are logging into a website, selecting values for multiple fields and clicking on submit button on page 1 which opens page2; here the page changes. So the `DOM tree` also gets changed. Selenium is now having the focus on the new `HTML DOM`. `WebElements` of the new `DOM` are attached now. So essentially the `WebElements` of the previous page are no more attached to the current `DOM`.

Now as you go back to Page1 and and try to find/search the same values which were already set earlier you will face a **`StaleElementReferenceException`**. All you have do is again fill out the fields (text fields/drop down etc).

Here is the official documentation on [**`StaleElementReferenceException`**](http://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp)

Comment: Hi Debanjan, what are your thoughts working with sessionstorage 
 - https://gist.github.com/roydekleijn/3976589

Comment: @Kapil Thanks, I work with `Selenium-Java` and `Selenium-Python` bindings, still now experimenting with `Selenium-JavaScript` bindings but your scope work looks pretty exciting and niche. I am pretty open to explore new Technologies. Let me know if I can contribute in your work as well.

Comment: No, i am not working on this. I am also learning. I just googled and find the solution for the question asked.